# Better control over Tessellation in OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glsl, tessellation

I spent the day working on an OpenGL application that will tessellate a mesh and apply a lens distortion. The goal is to be able to render wide angle shots for a variety of different lenses. So far I've got the shaders properly applying the distortion but I've been having issues controlling the tessellation the way I want to. Right now my Tessellation Control Shader just breaks a single triangle into a set number of smaller triangles, then I apply the lens distortion in in the Tessellation Evaluation Shader.

The problem I'm having with this approach is that when I have really large triangles in the scene, they tend to need more warping. This means they need to be tessellated more in order to ensure good looking results. Unfortunately, I can't compute the size of a triangle (in screen space) in the Vertex Shader or the Tessellation Control Shader, but I need to define the tessellation amount in the Tessellation Control shader.

My question is then, is there some way to get a hold of the entire primitive in OpenGL's programmable pipeline, compute some metrics about it, then use that information to control tessellation?

Here's some example images of the problem for clarity...

[image: Small Triangles Look Good]

Figure 1 (Above): Each Red or Green Square was originally 2 triangles, this example looks good because the triangles were small.

[image: Big Triangles Look Bad]

Figure 2 (Above): Each Red or Green Region was originally 2 triangles, this example looks bad because the triangles were small.

[image: Small Triangles Again]

Figure 3 (Above): Another example with small triangles but with a much, much larger grid. Notice how much things curve on the edges. Still looks good with tessellation level of 4.

[image: Really Big Triangles Bad]

Figure 4 (Above): Another example with large triangles, only showing center 4 columns because the image is unintelligible if more columns are present. This shows how very large triangles don't get tessellated well. If I set the tessellation really really high then this comes out nice. But then I'm performing a crazy amount of tessellation on smaller triangles too.

Comment: Have you considered simply using the `z` coordinate in clip-space? Patches farther away need less tessellation and ones closer need more as a general rule. This is often done for performance (to avoid sub-pixel triangles on distant patches), but it benefits image quality too.

Comment: @Andon Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not sure how it will solve the problem of long triangles since the distortion is only a function of x and y in clip space.

Comment: Oh, I think I misinterpreted what I was looking at. Yeah, that's not going to be particularly helpful in this case. You can actually compute the covered area of a patch in NDC space though if you add some bounding information per-patch (e.g. center and the radius of a sphere that bounds it).

Nevertheless, I think you're thinking about this all wrong. You can never know the size of the *triangles* before tessellation because they don't exist yet; you just have an abstract set of control points in your patch. You can get a hold of an entire primitive in a TCS, but it will be a patch primitive.

Comment: @Andon Of course!!! This is the first time I've actually used tessellation shaders and I didn't realize you had the entire patch available in the TCS. To be clear I'm using a single triangle as the patch at the moment and I didn't realize I could access all three coordinates from inside the TCS. With that I am able to to at least solve the problem of making long triangles tessellated more. If you make this an answer I'll go ahead and mark it as answered.

Comment: That would be awesome, thanks Andon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Tessellation Control Shader (TCS) you have *read* access to every vertex in the input patch primitive. While that sounds nice on paper, if you are trying to compute the maximum edge length of a patch, it would actually mean iterating over every vertex in the patch on every TCS invocation and that's not particularly efficient.

Instead, it may be more practical to pre-compute the patch's center in object-space and determine the radius of a sphere that tightly bounds the patch. Store this bounding information as an extra `vec4` attribute per-vertex, packed as shown below.

#### Pseudo-code for a TCS that computes the longest length of the patch in NDC-space

```
#version 420

uniform mat4 model_view_proj;

in vec4 bounding_sphere []; // xyz = center (object-space), w = radius

void main (void)
{
  vec4  center = vec4 (bounding_sphere [0].xyz, 1.0f);
  float radius =       bounding_sphere [0].w;

  // Transform object-space X extremes into clip-space
  vec4 min_0 = model_view_proj * (center - vec4 (radius, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
  vec4 max_0 = model_view_proj * (center + vec4 (radius, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

  // Transform object-space Y extremes into clip-space
  vec4 min_1 = model_view_proj * (center - vec4 (0.0f, radius, 0.0f, 0.0f));
  vec4 max_1 = model_view_proj * (center + vec4 (0.0f, radius, 0.0f, 0.0f));

  // Transform object-space Z extremes into clip-space
  vec4 min_2 = model_view_proj * (center - vec4 (0.0f, 0.0f, radius, 0.0f));
  vec4 max_2 = model_view_proj * (center + vec4 (0.0f, 0.0f, radius, 0.0f));

  // Transform from clip-space to NDC
  min_0 /= min_0.w; max_0 /= max_0.w;
  min_1 /= min_1.w; max_1 /= max_1.w;
  min_2 /= min_2.w; max_2 /= max_2.w;

  // Calculate the distance (ignore depth) covered by all three pairs of extremes
  float dist_0 = distance (min_0.xy, max_0.xy);
  float dist_1 = distance (min_1.xy, max_1.xy);
  float dist_2 = distance (min_2.xy, max_2.xy);

  // A max_dist >= 2.0 indicates the patch spans the entire screen in one direction
  float max_dist = max (dist_0, max (dist_1, dist_2));

  // ...
}
```

If you run your 4<sup>th</sup> diagram through this TCS, you should come up with a value for `max_dist` very nearly **2.0**, which means you need as much subdivision as possible. Meanwhile, many of the patches on the periphery of the sphere in the 3<sup>rd</sup> diagram will be close to **0.0**; they don't need much subdivision.

*This does not properly deal with situations where part of the patch is offscreen. You would need to clamp the NDC extremes to [**-1.0**,**1.0**] to properly handle those situations. Seemed like more trouble than it was worth.*

Comment: I really like this approach, its nice and clean. I did some testing and was able to get some nice looking results. I need to spend some more time working the math for the lens distortion models because the amount of tessellation doesn't scale linearly, but as a rule of thumb I'm using a weighted product of the radius of the bounding circle and the the center in clip space to determine the tessellation amount. Much, much better looking results. Thanks for all the help!